# How to parse JSON response and store values inside a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select async to load options from a input passed through a API. I get the JSON response that has a list inside it which has a field "FullName" I am attempting to go through the JSON file and store all the field names in an array. The array is then returned as the options.

Inside the JSON there is a list and the list contains the results and for each number there is a FullName

The format of the JSON response:

```
version:
status:
-status code
-status message
error:
result:
-paginate
list:
-0
--FullName
```

Below is my class I've shown where I think my issues lies with `-----`

```
class ReactSelectExample extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        selectedOption: {}
    }
  }

fetchData = (inputValue, callback) => {
    if (!inputValue) {
      callback([]);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
  fetch("-----API URL----" + inputValue, {
    method: "GET",
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    return resp.json()
  }) 
----------------
  .then((data) => {
      const tempArray = [];
     data.forEach((element) => {
            tempArray.push({ label: `${element.fullname}`, value: element.FullName });
     });
     callback(tempArray);   
---------------       
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
  });
});
}
}

 onSearchChange = (selectedOption) => {
    if (selectedOption) {

    this.setState({
        selectedOption
       });
    }
  };
  render() {
      return ( <div>
           <AsyncSelect
                value={this.state.selectedOption}
                loadOptions={this.fetchData}
                placeholder="Admin Name"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    this.onSearchChange(e);
                }}
                defaultOptions={false}
            />
      </div>)
  }

}
```

when I start it up and search all I see is loading but no options with names load in the. the error when I inspect the page I get the error 
`JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 of the column 1 of JSON data catch the hoop`

Comment: It'd be helpful if instead of the description of your json response you could provide the actual json.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get errors? Does *anything* happen? What debugging have you done?

Comment: "Below is my class I've shown where I think my issues lies with -----" — It doesn't. The error message suggests it is failing on `resp.json()` (likely because the response is not JSON).

Comment: @Quentin I thought it was that but when I right click and inspect the page I see that there is a Json response with all the information I need. I will double check to make sure though

Comment: @daformat I unfortunately can't

Comment: @Pointy I went ahead and edited my post thank you

Comment: Please look at array map function. It does what you are doing manually within the ——- lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a CORS policy issue. because the api I was using was external and didn't match my url, the JSON response was not being seen. I switched to calling the api on the backend because there is no CORS for server to server.